# What is the long ID that Linux assigns to a disk in /media/?

Tags: mount

For example, when I plug in an external hard drive disk enclosure via USB, sometimes the disk is automatically mounted in `/media/`.

For example, the disk might be mounted to

`/media/13f35f59-f023-4d98-b06f-9dfaebefd6c1`

or

`/media/4668484A68483B47`

What are those long IDs?

Comment: Presumably these are the same identifiers as blkid shows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The longer number is called a [Universally Unique Identifier](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID) (UUID). It is specified by the filesystem. There is a good [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) that gives more information on why and how it is used.

FAT filesystems are identified with a shorter ID (the "Volume serial number").  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_serial_number) suggests it's actually a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

It was probably mounted by `udisksd`. Look in syslog. On my system, inserting a USB stick results in this:

```
Aug  6 15:17:08 ubuntu udisksd[2856]: Mounted /dev/sdb1 at /media/mp/A88B-3652
```

`udisks` tries to provide a unique name for each drive or partition. It searches through all the symlinks that `udev` creates under `/dev/disk`. For removable media, it looks at the symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-uuid` and `/dev/disk/by-label`. For nonremovable media, it looks in `/dev/disk/by-id`.

The entries in the `by-uuid` directory are often, but not always, UUIDs. In your example, the UUID 13f35f59-f023-4d98-b06f-9dfaebefd6c1 was likely generated by a command like `mke2fs`, which creates filesystems.
In the case of my USB stick, A88B-3652 is actually the volume serial number of its fat32 partition.

The entries in the `by-label` directory are Volume Labels on CD or DVD discs, for example "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64", or filesystem labels created with the -L option to `mke2fs` or `tune2fs`.

The entries in the `by-id` directory are often of the form *bustype-manufacturer_device_serialnumber*, with a -part*n* appended for each partition.